# iOS - Sending sender-linked variables through a segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Through using a loop I've programmatically created a bunch of UIButtons. Each of these triggers the same segue to another View Controller which is supposed to display some information related to the button.

For this to work, I need to send at least one attribute/variable linked to the specific button tapped through the segue.

One option I tried was creating a new UIButton class to hold the attribute.

```
class statButton: UIButton {
    var buttonIndex = Int()
}
```

If this even works, how would I access that data here:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "StatDetailSegue" {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? StatDetailViewController {
            destinationVC.statTitle = //  need to access here
        }
    }
}
```

The variable I need to send is a value in a dictionary

Comment: The parameter `sender` will be the button that was pressed. You can use it to find the relevant data and pass it to `destinationVC`

Comment: `(sender as? statButton).buttonIndex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that the sender is a `statButton`, and then cast its `buttonIndex` property to a proper String:

```
if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? StatDetailViewController, 
   let index = (sender as? statButton).buttonIndex {
        destinationVC.statTitle = String(index) //this is supposing that destinationVC.statTitle expects a String
}
```

**P.S**: It is a [convention](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#naming) in Swift to have the names of classes with an uppercase first letter:

```
class statButton: UIButton { ... }
```